# How to empty the form before loading in magento 2

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, magento2.2, modal-popup

I have created popup modal using ajax and it works successfully. But once the form submitted, it saves in DB. But if I click again to perform action, It simply **shows prefilled message instead of new form in popup**. How to resolve it??

**history.phtml**

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="click" class="click-me" data-id="<?= $_order->getEntityId(); ?>">Cancel</a>
</div>
<div id="popup-modal" style="display:none;">
    <form action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() . 'sales/index/index'; ?> " method="post" id="form-validate"
          enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'
          data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
          echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
        <div id="result"></div>
        <div>
            <label>Reason:</label>
            <textarea id="reason" rows="4" cols="6" name="reason"></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function ($,
                  modal) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: 'Reason for Cancelled the item',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('submit'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        var form_data = jQuery("#reason").val();

                        var post_id = $('#click').data('id');

                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() . 'oxsales/index/index'; ?>",
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {'id': post_id, 'form_data': form_data},

                            success: function (response) {

                                $("#result").html("Order cancelled successfully");

                            },
                            error: function (response) {
                                $("#result").html("Error");
                            }
                        });

                        this.closeModal();

                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
            $(".click-me").on('click', function () {
                $('#reason').empty();
                $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this.closeModal(); from submit button action in your current code and add another button which will close the modal.

```
buttons: [
    {
      //here is your submit button, remove this.closeModal();
    },
    {
      text: $.mage.__('close'),                                                        
      class: '',
      click: function () {
        this.closeModal();
      }
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `$('#reason').val("");` in your click `.click-me` event like below:

```
$(".click-me").on('click', function () {
     $('#reason').valu("");
     $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
});
```